# retrieve data from pivot table many to many relation ship laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

i made a many to many relationship in laravel and it works fine but when i want to retrive and show my data some thing strange happens 
now i want to show the clients which are assigned to the logged in user  so here is my code 
client model :

```
public function sellmanlist(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User' , 'client_user','client_id');
}
```

Controller and the method for retreive

```
public function myclient(Client $client){
    $user_id =Auth::user()->id;
    $client = Client::with('sellmanlist')->firstOrFail();
    return view('admin.client.myclient',compact('user_id','client'));
}
```

and here is the view that i am testing already

```
@foreach($client->sellmanlist as $sellman )
            @php(
            $sell_id = $sellman->pivot->user_id
            )
            @if($user_id === $sell_id)
                {{$client->id}}
                {{$client->title}}
            <br>
                @endif
            @endforeach
```

but this only shows the client id of 1 2 times and here is my pivot table

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('client_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('client_id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: can you add your `User` model with its relationship in your question ?

Comment: should i define the viseversa relation on usermodel ?? like hasmany clients ? cause i dont have any realtion on my user model but every thing working on saving the data and updating it

Comment: better if you add a relationship in user model `belongsToMany`

Comment: i have added answer  check it once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a reverse `belongsToMany` relationship in User model for `Client`

User Model

```
public function clients(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Client','client_user');
}
```

Now fetch clients for logged in user in controller

```
public function myclient(Client $client){
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->load('clients'); //lazy-eager loading
    return view('admin.client.myclient',compact('user','client'));
}
```

Display it in view

```
@foreach($user->clients as $client )
   {{$client->id}}
   {{$client->title}}
   <br>
@endforeach
```

Comment: that solved the problem for me :) i am a little confused now i have to check it several time to understand what just happened :) ty man it helped